# How to infer the accuracy from cluster solutions from hierarchical clusters using Scipy in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, data-science, hierarchical-clustering

I am building a hierarchical cluster using scipy in python using the iris dataset. Following is my code:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
Z = linkage(X,'complete')
plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
dendrogram(Z)
plt.show()
kclusters = fcluster(Z, 3, criterion='maxclust')
```

As you can see I am trying to retrieve the cluster solution with 3 clusters (k=3). Upon doing this I get an array that specifies which cluster each instance is in. However, how can I know which cluster has the majority of 'Versicolor' or 'Setosa' or 'Virginica' instances. How can I get the accuracy or purity of any of the three clusters actually or draw any kind of inference. From `kclusters` I am just getting a rough idea regarding the distribution of the instances across the three clusters but nothing more. How will I know if this clustering method is working well for the iris data set? Kindly help me if possible.

Comment: If you want to know how many clusters are better, you can use elbow method (for example https://datascience103579984.wordpress.com/2019/12/05/clustering-methods-with-scipy-from-datacamp/3/). If you want to cross-validate other methods, you can use `sklearn` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html

Comment: If by the `"elbow method"` you decide based on the loss of your clusters, I wouldn't rely on that method to find `k`. Reason is that the more clusters you add, the lower the loss, so that method would always end up recommending `k=# points` (it's logical, the solution which provides 0 loss is the one whereby each data point is its own cluster, which is obviously useless for clustering purposes). Instead look at things like `BIC`: https://towardsdatascience.com/an-intuitive-explanation-of-the-bayesian-information-criterion-71a7a3d3a5c5